# What should i do to restart my flutter/dart sdk for it to function well

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, dart

[This shows up aand goes off immediately when i run flutter doctor or any flutter command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tcxo.png)

I set up the flutter enviroment early this year, and it has been dormant till now. Me trying to use it currently, its not functioning well.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in the Flutter install directory:

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

[source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted)